# Django change language in html

Tags: python, html, django, translation

In the [Django Translation documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/translation/), it gives this way of changing the language of the site:

```
{% load i18n %}

<form action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ redirect_to }}" />
    <select name="language">
        {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
        {% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
        {% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
        {% for language in languages %}
            <option value="{{ language.code }}"{% if language.code == LANGUAGE_CODE %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>
                {{ language.name_local }} ({{ language.code }})
            </option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

What I want to do instead is have two buttons(two divs actually) that when pressed change the language accordingly(el for Greek and en for English). How can I change that form into what I want to do? Sorry if it's simple, I'm not that good with forms...
I tried something else:

```
<div id="english">
                <img id="english_flag" src="{% static "en.png" %}"/>
            </div>
            <script>
            $('#english').click(function(){
                  $.ajax({
                           type: "POST",
                           url: "{% url 'set_language' %}",
                           data: {'language': 'en', 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
                           success: function(response) {
                                location.reload();
                            },
                            error: function(rs, e) {
                                   alert(e);
                            }
                      });
                })
            </script>
            <div id="greek">
                <img id="greek_flag" src="{% static "el.png" %}"/>
            </div>
            <script>
            $('#greek').click(function(){
                  $.ajax({
                           type: "POST",
                           url: "{% url 'set_language' %}",
                           data: {'language': 'el', 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
                           success: function(response) {
                                location.reload();
                            },
                            error: function(rs, e) {
                                   alert(e);
                            }
                      });
                })
            </script>
```

And it's working just fine. A bit more testing and I'm going to answer my question...

Comment: You should have a go yourself first and then ask for help if you get stuck. There's not a lot to change, you could just loop over the languages and have an individual form for each language,  or look at what the form is actually doing

Comment: I want to add an image with the appropriate flag for each country, so the the looping thing won't work...

Comment: Of course it will. Just add an image tag. Maybe reuse the language name and add `.png` at the end to make ik a reference to an image? Or use the language name as class name and add the flag with css.It won't work if you do not give it a try.

Comment: OK, I'll see and come back with some code to show...

Comment: Edited question, did something different...