# Django: translation in templates not working

Tags: django

**Django 1.11**

I can't make Django translate templates in my project. 
Messages were compiled and recompiled.

Could you give me a kick here?

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
...
    'frame',
...
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru-RU'
USE_I18N = True
```

**frame/templates/frame/frame_form.html**

```
{% extends 'general/cbv/general_form.html' %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block title %}
    <h1>{% trans "Create frame" %}</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

**frame/locale/ru_RU/LC_MESSAGES/django.po**

```
#: templates/frame/frame_form.html:5
msgid "Create frame"
msgstr "Создать сюжет"
```

**tree**

```
├── frame
...
│   ├── locale
│   │   └── ru_RU
│   │       └── LC_MESSAGES
│   │           ├── django.mo
│   │           └── django.po
...
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── frame
│   │       ├── frame_form.html
```

Comment: How your [`LOCALE_PATHS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#locale-paths) is configured? Also try rename the dir from `ru_RU` into `ru`.

Comment: It is not configured. I didn't think it to be necessary. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-translations Item 2: locale in INSTALLED_APPS  should be looked through.

Comment: Also: make sure the  django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware middleware is present in your settings file

Comment: LocaleMiddleware is not necessary. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference "If you want to let each individual user specify which language they prefer". I don't want to let them select the language.

Comment: Strange situation. I played with it: added LOCALE_PATHS and LocalMiddleware. Then deleted both. And now it works. I don't know how it happened. But not it is translating. Could it have anything with caching in Django? If yes, how to clear cache?

Comment: There should be no caching unless you explicitly activated it. But anyway it's good that it works now :-) LOCALE_PATHS is definitely not required, but I really thought the middleware was

Comment: Pardon. Can I really activate caching specially for localization? Those locale strings suit perfectly for caching. I'd be a bit astonished if they were not cached.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Check for the following:

**Settings.py**

In your `settings.py`

1)  Make sure Middleware classes is in the following order

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',

]
```

2) Set your language code default:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

USE_I18N = True
```

3) Put the language you want to translate to a list can be found [here](http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html)

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

#Example for English and German
LANGUAGES =[ ('en', _('English')),
('de', _('German')),]
```

4) Set your Locale path folder (This is where your language translations will appear)

```
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'locale'),
)
```

**URL.py**

Check you have this link in the main URL conf file `url.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('YOUR APP.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),  #Make sure this is present
]
```

**HTML template**

After you have this checked and your `HTML template` done with the `{% load i18n %}` before any of the `{% trans "FOO" %}` on your html page and some way to change the languages. You might also want something like this dropdown:  [Django change language in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38280307/django-change-language-in-html) to debug language changes

**Creating and modifying .po files**

1) Create django.po files in the locale directory that you specify in the settings.py (LOCALE_PATHS) using the following command in the *command line* to create the .po files for example english would be:

```
   python manage.py makemessages -l en   #en = english replace en for other languages
```

This creates a directory with YOUR_LANGUAGE/LC_MESSAGES/django.po

Note that some languages will not show up unless it is capitalized for some reason such as simplified `chinese zh-Hans` instead of `zh-hans` not really sure why.

2) Go into the django.po of the language you want to change and change the `msgstr ""`

```
msgid "Create frame"
msgstr "Создать сюжет" #This area had translated string added
```

3) Compile the messages and restart the server in the commandline

```
# Compile messages 
django-admin compilemessages #this creates a django.mo file in LC_MESSAGES folder

#Run server
python manage.py runserver
```

The text should change when you switch languages using the dropdown menu or whatever way you chose.

4) If you add new translation tags you have to remake the messages and recompile them in the commandline and then runserver

```
#Make messages for all your languages
django-admin makemessages -a

# Compile messages
django-admin compilemessages
```

Comment: For me it was missing compilemessages. I tend to forget that.